# What's the impact of HREFLANG pointing to a redirected URL for EN-US?

Tags: seo, drupal, hreflang

I'm doing some international SEO work on a Drupal site.  I noticed this on the EN-US home page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us" href="https://www.example.com/home" />
```

Take special note of the `/home` subfolder there.  I'm told that Drupal needs this and it's standard stuff.  But if you go to this URL, it redirects twice.  Once to the home page (307) and then to the https version (301)

The English site is the "default" site.  The other languages have a perfect match for all URLs in hreflang and canonical directives. (`/france`, `/germany`, etc.)

From an SEO point of view, the discrepancy & redirects bug me.

**What impact would these differences have for SEO?**

Comment: I'm trying to understand why this happens.  Is it because the home page is powered by the `/home` URL in Drupal?  So when you view the root URL, the code thinks that it is for `/home`?